# Keyword error when implementing Scatterv in mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi, keyerror, mpi4py

I'm trying to use `Scatterv` to distribute parts of an array to each of my processors, but the line where I run the `Scatterv` call fails, and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-16-e1f960b94347>", line 1, in <module>
    comm.Scatterv([init_data, (sendcount,split)], init_data_local, root=0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 626, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatterv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 538, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 440, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_send
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 266, in mpi4py.MPI.message_vector
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 100, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic
KeyError: '38w'
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is a reproducible example of the code. Changing the data type of the init_data array changes the number following `KeyError`, but still gives the same error. My choice of `'<U38'` as the dtype is because that is what `np.loadtxt` uses when loading the array within my actual code.

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

if rank==0:
    init_data=np.ones((5187,3), dtype='<U38')
    length=len(init_data[:,0])
else:
    length=None
    init_data=None

length=comm.bcast(length, root=0)

sendcount=[]
split=[]
for r in range(size):
    split.append(r*length//size)
    if r<size-1:
        sendcount.append(length//size)
    else:
        sendcount.append(length-(r*length//size))
sendcount=tuple(sendcount)
split=tuple(split)

init_data_local=np.empty((sendcount[rank], 3),dtype=str)

comm.Scatterv([init_data, (sendcount,split)], init_data_local, root=0)
```

Comment: Can you share the data being passed to Scattterv? `KeyError` means a dictionary did not contain a requested key so it could be a problem with the inputs.

Comment: Sure! The init_data is an Array of str1216 with dimensions (5187, 3). I split that between four processors, so sendcount is a tuple (1296, 1296, 1296, 1297) and split is a tuple (0, 1296, 2592, 3888). Finally, I make init_data_local with: init_data_local=np.empty((sendcount[rank], 3),dtype=str).

Comment: @rgswope please edit your question and upload a [MCVE] so we can all look at the same source code.

Comment: Ok, just added it. Let me know if there's anything else I can do that'll help.

Comment: what if you use `byte` instead of `str`?

Comment: That gives me KeyError: '38s'.